# accumulate tail recursive function on list in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am doing assignment for my college. I need to create recursive function.

My list_t interface contain following functions:

```
List Interface
The file recursive.h defines the type "list_t" and the following operations on lists:
// EFFECTS: returns true if list is empty, false otherwise
bool list_isEmpty​ (const list_t& list);
// EFFECTS: returns an empty list.
list_t list_make​ ();
// EFFECTS: given the list (list) make a new list consisting of
// the new element followed by the elements of the
// original list.
list_t list_make​ (int elt, const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the first element of list
int list_first​ (const list_t& list);
// REQUIRES: list is not empty
// EFFECTS: returns the list containing all but the first element of list
list_t list_rest​ (const list_t& list);
// MODIFIES: cout
// EFFECTS: prints list to cout.
void list_print​ (const list_t& list);
```

for this list i need to create function describe below

```
/*
* REQUIRES: fn must be associative.
* EFFECTS: return identity if list is empty.
* Otherwise, return the tail recursive equivalent of
* fn(list_first(list), accumulate(list_rest(list), fn, identity).
* Be sure to make your code tail recursive!
*
* For example, if you have the following function:
*
* int add(int x, int y);
*
* Then the following invocation returns the sum of all elements:
*
* accumulate(list, add, 0);
*
* The "identity" argument is typically the value for which
* fn(X, identity) == X and fn(identity, X) == X for any X.
*/
int accumulate (list_t list, int (*fn)(int, int), int identity);
```

i do already have function ready for sum and product if its relevant

the function also need to follow below rules

● Each of these procedures must be tail recursive. For full credit, your routines must provide the
correct result and provide an implementation that is tail recursive.
● In writing these functions, you may use only recursion and selection. You are NOT allowed to use goto, for, while, or do‐while
● No static or global variables
● If you define any helper functions, be sure to declare them " static ", so that they are not
visible outside your program file. See the appendix for more information about tail recursion
and helper functions.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how to implement this function

Comment: You don't expect us to do your homework, do you ?

Comment: no i do not..i do not understand what type of function do i need to implement.i don't want source code i just need explanation

Answer (score 0):

As a kind of starting point, let's implement `sum` by hand instead of through `accumulate`.

**Not using tail recursion:**

There are two cases; either the list is empty or it isn't.

If the list is empty, return 0.
If it isn't, add the list's first element to the sum of the rest of the list.

```
int sum(list_t list)
{
    return list_isEmpty(list) 
           ? 0 
           : list_first(list) + sum(list_rest(list));
}
```

This isn't tail-recursive because after the recursive call returns, we perform an addition with the result.

**Using tail recursion:**

To make this tail-recursive, we need to introduce a parameter where we accumulate the partial results, so we define a helper function.
(The "if you define" in your description is in fact a hint that you should.)

Again, there are two cases; either the list is empty or it isn't.

If the list is empty, return the accumulator.
If it isn't, add the list's first element to the accumulator and pass that to the recursive call that sums the rest of the list.

```
static int sum_helper(list_t list, int accumulator)
{
    return list_isEmpty(list) 
           ? accumulator 
           : sum_helper(list_rest(list), list_first(list) + accumulator);
}
```

This is tail-recursive because nothing happens after the recursive call.

Now we can define `sum` in terms of `sum_helper`:

```
int sum(list_t list)
{
    return sum_helper(list, 0);
}
```

Implementating a tail-recursive `accumulate` follows the same pattern - add a parameter where you accumulate the result.

You should also follow the advice to "See the appendix for more information about tail recursion and helper functions", and you can look up the term "left fold" for more information about this particular function.